# dynamically generate grid with data using javascript or ajax or anything in mvc.mvc

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a requirement where user will select the datatable and according to that grid should be displayed in mvc. The grid should be generated dynamically. Any ideas.?

Answer (score 0):

i recomended for generate data tables from DB, by ajax datatable, for high performance and paginate data.

https://www.datatables.net/manual/ajax